# how to post with multiple value in a key with retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

i create an API on server side, when i tried to post with `POSTMAN` like this..

```
tokenku:2040asdfasdfasdfCBLCPTDPaS99P7L0N9LYP8X4sdfasdf
    userdetail:2
    invoiceNo:(AUTO)
    invoiceDate:20/01/2017
    customer:6
    uangMuka:0.00
    description:keterangan aja, wkwkwkwwk
    item:38
    qty:10
    unit:1
    price:10000
    discount:0.00
    dt:P
    totalberat:100
    province:DKi Jakarta
    city:DKI Jakarta
    alamatTujuan:Jl. Villa Kapuk Mas 1 Blok F2 No.10
    ppn:null
    item:40
    qty:10
    unit:1
    price:10000
    discount:0.00
    dt:P
    ongkir:18500
```

[image]

see carefully, i sent two times with key `item`,`qty`,`unit`,`price`,`discount` and `dt`.

[image]

i tried with `POSTMAN` and it success when the `server` receive that.

now i am trying to implement that value with `retrofit2`

this is what i tried.

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/orderPenjualan/save")
Call<String> postOrder(@Field("invoiceNo") String invoiceNo,
                       @Field("invoiceDate") String invoiceDate,
                       @Field("customer") String userId,
                       @Field("ppn") Object nullValue, //how to post null value
                       @Field("uangMuka") String cashAdvance,
                       @Field("description") String description,
                       //loop parameter if more than one item
                       @Field("item") int itemId,
                       @Field("qty") double qty,
                       @Field("unit") int unit,
                       @Field("price") double price,
                       @Field("discount") double discount,
                       @Field("dt") String point,
                       @Field("userdetail") String userdetailConstant,
                       @Field("tokenku") String tokenkuConstant);

@Multipart
@POST("api/orderPenjualan/save")
Call<String> postOrderWithBody(@Part MultipartBody.Part fields //body not working
);

@POST("api/orderPenjualan/save")
Call<String> postOrderWithMap(@Query("invoiceNo") String invoiceNo,
                              @Query("invoiceDate") String invoiceDate,
                              @Query("customer") int userId,
                              @Query("ppn") String nullValue, //how to post "null" value
                              @Query("uangMuka") double cashAdvance, //0.00
                              @Query("description") String description,
                              @Query("totalberat") int weight,
                              @Query("province") String province,
                              @Query("city") String city,
                              @Query("alamatTujuan") String destAddress,
                              @Query("ongkir") String ongkir,
                              //loop parameter if more than one item
                              @Body() RequestBody fields, //body not working
                              @Query("userdetail") String userdetailConstant,
                              @Query("tokenku") String tokenkuConstant);
```

when i tried to execute this code, the server just receive 
`item:38
    qty:10
    unit:1
    price:10000
    discount:0.00
    dt:P`

not with this
`item:40
    qty:10
    unit:1
    price:10000
    discount:0.00
    dt:P`

before i use retrofit, i use this code to handle

```
 for(int i=0; i<mItemDataItem.size(); i++) {
                            HelperAddItem hai = mItemDataItem.get(i);

                            final String FmItemId = String.valueOf(hai.getmItemId());
                            final String FmItemQty = String.valueOf(hai.getmQty());
                            final String FmUnitId = String.valueOf(hai.getmUnitId());
                            final String FmPrice = String.valueOf(hai.getmPrice());
                            final String FmDiscount = String.valueOf(hai.getmDiscountNominal());
                            final String FmDT = (hai.getmDiscountType() == 1 ? "P" : "PS");

                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", String.valueOf(FmItemId)));
                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", String.valueOf(FmItemQty)));
                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unit", String.valueOf(FmUnitId)));
                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", String.valueOf(FmPrice)));
                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("discount", String.valueOf(FmDiscount)));
                            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt", FmDT));
                        }
```

but how about in retrofit2?

---

this code work for me...
but i want to use retrofit2

```
AsyncTask postServer = new AsyncTask() {
protected String mResponse = "";
protected ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
dialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckOutActivity.this);
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setMessage("Harap tunggu, Sedang menyimpan Order...");
dialog.show();
    }

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList parameter = new ArrayList();
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("invoiceNo", invoice));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("invoiceDate", invoiceDate));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customer", String.valueOf(userId)));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ppn", "null"));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uangMuka", String.valueOf(uangMuka)));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", String.valueOf(des)));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("province", String.valueOf(city.getProvince())));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", String.valueOf(city.getCity_name())));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alamatTujuan", String.valueOf(detailAddress)));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ongkir", String.valueOf(selectedOngkir)));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userdetail", Constants.USERDETAIL));
        parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tokenku", Constants.TOKENKU));

for (int i = 0; i < orderList.size(); i++) {
            ProductOrderModel current = orderList.get(i);

            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", String.valueOf(current.getItem())));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", String.valueOf(current.getQty())));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unit", String.valueOf(current.getUnit())));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", String.valueOf(current.getPrice())));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("discount", String.valueOf(current.getDiscount())));
            parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt", current.getDt()));
        }
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106:8080/api/orderPenjualan/save");
try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameter, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
return mResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: "+mResponse);
//Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
postServer.execute();
```

Comment: Why would you want that. Its asking for trouble

Comment: @TimCastelijns no, when the server receive 2 values with the same key, the values become array... like this.. `item:[38, 40], qty:[10, 10], unit:[1, 1], price:[10000, 10000]`

Comment: That seems odd. How can an item be 2 items?

Comment: @TimCastelijns not strange, its look like a form in html, when you have multiple `input='text'` with `name="item"`, it will become array

Comment: @TimCastelijns on the last projects, i loop this code `parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", String.valueOf(FmItemId)));, it works for me, but i dont know in `retrofit2`

Answer (score 0):

Following this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-multiple-query-parameters-of-same-name you will be able to add multiple query parameters with the same name